# jquery animate opacity vs display:none

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

If a element has a display:none on it in the CSS, then animating the opacity from 0 to 1 in jQuery doesn't make the element visible.

why?

what do I need to add in animate() to make it visible?

```
el.css({
            opacity: 0,
            left: - 200
          }).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
            left: 0
          }, {
            duration: 333
          });
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'd need to show it first using the [`show()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method.

If your element isn't already at opacity 0, then you'd probably want to set that first:

```
.css('opacity',0).show().animate({opacity:1});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/DnE7M/1/

---

Or you could just use the [`fadeIn()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method, which should take care of the `display` as well.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/DnE7M/

---

**EDIT:** *To make it relevant to the code added to the question:*

```
el.css({
        opacity: 0,
        left: - 200
      })
   .stop()
   .show()     // <-- make the element able to be displayed
   .animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: 0
      }, {
        duration: 333
      });
```

You could also do it right in the call to the [`css()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
el.css({
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'block',  // <-- 'block' or whatever is appropriate for you
        left: - 200
      })
   .stop()
   .animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: 0
      }, {
        duration: 333
      });
```